# GWT throws error saying that it can't find method from my RequestFactory interface but some methods work

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

Could you please tell me what is the meaning of `Could not find method in implementation com.mine.courierApp.server.dao.OrderDao matching descriptor (Ljava/lang/Long;)V for operation OjO7dPbbLTZAEEKwSdsHj5v6Hzw=` and how to fix it ?

Here is full call-stack:

```
Feb 27, 2012 2:07:13 AM com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator die
SEVERE: Could not find method in implementation com.mine.courierApp.server.dao.OrderDao matching descriptor (Ljava/lang/Long;)V for operation OjO7dPbbLTZAEEKwSdsHj5v6Hzw=
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mine.courierApp.server.dao.OrderDao.delete(java.lang.Long)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveDomainMethod(ResolverServiceLayer.java:138)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveDomainMethod(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:152)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.FindServiceLayer.resolveDomainMethod(FindServiceLayer.java:46)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveDomainMethod(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:152)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveDomainMethod(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:152)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveDomainMethod(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:104)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.resolveDomainMethod(ServiceLayerCache.java:176)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:440)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:225)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:127)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    at com.mine.courierApp.server.CustomRequestFactoryServlet.doPost(CustomRequestFactoryServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:363)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I'm totally puzzled because some methods of my RequestContext interface work just fine. Here is my interface:

```
public interface AdminRequestFactory extends RequestFactory
{
    // value = interface on server side, locator = class that returns instance of the object that implements "value"
    @Service(value = OrderDao.class, locator = InjectingServiceLocator.class)
    public interface OrderRequestContext extends RequestContext
    {
        Request<List<OrderProxy>> listAll();
        Request<Void> saveOrder(OrderProxy order);
        Request<Void> delete(Long id);
        Request<Void> saveOrganization(OrganizationProxy organization);
        Request<OrganizationProxy> findOrganizationById(long id);
    }

    OrderRequestContext contextOrder();
}
```

saveOrder and saveOrganization work but calls to listAll, delete and findOrganizationById cause exception shown above. From vague language of the exception I understand that definition of methods in interface doesn't match methods in implementing class. But I don't see any difference from working methods!

Here is how my Dao class look like:

```
public class OrderDao
{
    @Inject Ofy ofy;

    public OrderDao()
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    List<Order> listAll()
    {
        return ofy.load().type(Order.class).list();
    }

    void delete(Long id)
    {
        ofy.delete(Key.create(Order.class, id));
    }

    public void saveOrder(final Order order)
    {
        ofy.transact(new Ofy.VoidWork()
        {
            @Override
            public void vrun(Ofy ofy)
            {
                ofy.save(order);
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveOrganization(final Organization organization)
    {
        ofy.transact(new Ofy.VoidWork()
        {
            @Override
            public void vrun(Ofy ofy)
            {
                Key<Organization> key = ofy.fact().allocateId(Organization.class);
                organization.setId(key.getId());

                ofy.save(organization.getContactPerson());
                ofy.save(organization);
            }
        });
    }

    public Organization findOrganizationById(long id)
    {
        return ofy.load(Organization.class, id);
    }
}
```

And finally here is how I make calls in client code:

```
orderRequestContext.delete(1L).fire(new Receiver<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void arg0)
    {
        createConfirmationDialogBox("Deleted!").center();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ServerFailure error)
    {
        createConfirmationDialogBox(error.getMessage()).center();
    }
});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Ljava/lang/Long;)V` represents a method taking a single `Long` argument and with a `void` return type.

Your `delete` method, which matches this definition, is not `public`, this is the problem (the `listAll` method has the same issue)